# Escape XML special characters upon convert

Tags: sql, xml, csv, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have working **csv** splitter for my needs.

You can just grab and run it as is:

```
declare @t table(data varchar(max))
insert into @t select 'a,b,c,d'
insert into @t select 'e,,,h'

;with cte(xm) as 
(
    select convert(xml,'<f><e>' + replace(data,',', '</e><e>') + '</e></f>') as xm 
    from @t
)
select
    xm.value('/f[1]/e[1]','varchar(32)'),
    xm.value('/f[1]/e[2]','varchar(32)'),
    xm.value('/f[1]/e[3]','varchar(32)'),
    xm.value('/f[1]/e[4]','varchar(32)')
from cte
```

Only issue is, that if I introduce an XML sensitive character in the **data**, like **&**:

```
insert into @t select 'i,j,&,k'
```

It fails with error: character 24, illegal character

One solution is to replace **&** character to **&amp** on the fly, like this:

```
select convert(xml,'<f><e>' + replace(replace(data,'&','&amp'),',', '</e><e>') + '</e></f>') as xm
```

but there are several dozens of special XML characters which I need to escape upon convert, and I can't really nest dozens **replace(replace(replace(...** functions in there. That's what i did and it is messy.

How the above code can be modified to escape XML sensitive characters, and produce the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: Just abandon that one and use a different splitter. You dont have a "working csv splitter" because of the issues you are encountering. See https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings for some others.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, but already saw that page. None of them is good. I cannot create extra functions, neither do CLR, and i just hit rock bottom with recursion quickly.

Comment: You can easily create a virtual numbers table using a  CTE and use a numbers table based one without creating any objects.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, but extremely overkill. Please understand its not just about CSV splitting, its generally about "escape XML chars" upon convert.

Comment: possibly this. https://rextester.com/WVILZ17601

Comment: @MartinSmith That's the one Martin. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have got your answer by Martin Smith already. But I think, it is worth to place an answer here for followers. Want to provide some explanantion and furthermor, the rextester-link might not be reachable in future...

If you think of a string in a table like this ...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeXMLstring VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('This is a string with forbidden characters like "<", ">" or "&"');
```

-- ... you can easily add XML-tags:

```
SELECT '<root>' + SomeXMLstring + '</root>'
FROM @mockup ;
```

--The result would look like XML

```
<root>This is a string with forbidden characters like "<", ">" or "&"</root>
```

--But it is not! You can test this, the `CAST( AS XML)` will fail:

```
SELECT CAST('<root>This is a string with forbidden characters like "<", ">" or "&"</root>' AS XML);
```

--Sometimes people try to do their own replaces and start to replace `<, > and &` with the corresponding entities `&lt;, &gt; and &amp;`. But this will need a lot of replacements in order to be *safe*.

--But XML is doing all this for us implicitly

```
SELECT SomeXMLstring 
FROM @mockup
FOR XML PATH('')
```

--This is the result

```
<SomeXMLstring>This is a string with forbidden characters like "&lt;", "&gt;" or "&amp;"</SomeXMLstring>
```

--And the funny thing is: We can easily create a nameless element with `AS [*]`:

```
SELECT SomeXMLstring AS [*]
FROM @mockup
FOR XML PATH('')
```

--The result is the same, but without the tags:

```
This is a string with forbidden characters like "&lt;", "&gt;" or "&amp;"
```

--Although this is looking like XML in SSMS, this will be implicitly casted to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` when used as a string.

--You can use this for implicit escaping of a string wherever you feel the need to build a XML with string concatenation:

```
SELECT CAST('<root>' + (SELECT SomeXMLstring AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')) + '</root>' AS XML)
FROM @mockup ;
```

### To finally answer your question

This line must use the trick:

```
select convert(xml,'<f><e>' + replace((SELECT data AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',', '</e><e>') + '</e></f>') as xm
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer. Martin was quicker but this is more detailed, actually teaching a thing or two about XML in SQL. I'll mark this an answer then.